# How do I start doing Automation with Salesforce?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently writing some automation with Salesforce, Python and Selenium. My problem is that some of the Dynamic Elements are not reachable. However, I would like to know a better way to build a better test.

Example:

```
<input lightning-input_input="" type="text" id="input-45" maxlength="120" name="Name" required="" class="slds-input" aria-describedby="help-message-45">
```

Python Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('slds-template__container > input[name="Name]').send_keys('MockData Test')
```

The problem is that is not calling this element it says that is unable to locate or find the element. Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: So, you are taking the normal way and use the API?

Comment: No, I'm not using the API, but I could if I need it. I just need some direction

Comment: Is there more than one input on the page with the attribute `name="Name"`? If not, just drop the first part of your selector and just use `input[name="Name"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("slds-input")`
(be sure to specify the nth occurrence of the class)